# How can python merges a list of sets and return them as a set?

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list of sets like this:

```
set_list = [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 1, 6}, {2, 3, 6}, {1, 5, 8}]
```

Now I want to merge all of the sets together and return a set of all sets like this:

```
final_set = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8}
```

I have used this code but it is not working correctly:

```
tmp_list = []
final_set = set(tmp_list.append(elem) for elem in set_list)
```

What should I do?

Comment: "it is not working correctly": Please provide details.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use unpacking with `set().union` for a clean one-liner.

```py
>>> set().union(*set_list)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8}
```

Comment: This "accidentally" works by sending in the first element of set_list as "self". It is better to use `set().union(*set_list)` so that you still get the correct result for `set_list = []` instead of an exception.

Comment: @wim I have changed it to `set().union`. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [*`reduce`* functio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)n from [*`functools`* module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html).

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> set_list = [{1,2,3}, {4,5,1,6}, {2,3,6}, {1,5,8}]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, set_list)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the list and create a union of all sets:

```
new_set = set()
for i in set_list:
    new_set =  set.union(new_set, i)
print(new_set)
```

Output:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8}
```

Comment: Note that as you do union in-place you might use `.update` without need to assignment, i.e. instead of `new_set = set.union(new_set, i)` do `new_set.update(i)`

Answer (score 2):

You might do that using comprehension as follows

```
set_list = [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 1, 6}, {2, 3, 6}, {1, 5, 8}]
final_set = set(elem for sub in set_list for elem in sub)
print(final_set)
```

output

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8}
```

Explanation: this is simple adaptation of list-of-lists flattener comprehension which can be used as `set`s are iterable.